# JPA Repository Join - Continuous Loop of data when retrieving data from DB

Tags: java, spring, jpa, join, repository

I have two repositories - User and Address.

User has a one to one relationship with Address and they are linked by ID. See below code snippets. When I pull data using a JPA repository, I get basically a constant loop of data.

EG:

```
<Data>
 <User>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Mary</name>
   <dob>21/01/1990</dob>
   <Address> 
      <id>1<id>
      <address>123 Main Street</address>
       <User>
         <id>1</id>
          <name>Mary</name>
          <dob>21/01/1990</dob>
        <Address> 
          <id>1<id>
          <address>123 Main Street</address>
         <User>
            ....
```

and so on like this causing my query to take a large amount of time to run. Is there anyway to stop the User object from being returned within the Address object? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
 public class Address{

@Id
@Column()
private String id;

@Column()
private String address;

@OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private User user;
```

}

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "User")
 public class User{

@Id
@Column()
private String id;

@Column()
private String name;

@Column()
private String dob;

@OneToOne ()
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Address address;
```

}

Comment: is your loop really from JPA loading, or is it from the conversion of the model to JSON? If a relationship is marked as lazy, it won't loaded from the database unless your application is calling something, like getXXX on that relationship.

Comment: I think so. If I debug at the findAll() point in the repository, and check what it returns I can see the User Object and within that I see the Address object. Within the address for user I get the following error. Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.example.User.toString()

Comment: I fixed the above error message - that was down to the toString() method included in lombok. So yeah its still looping  even though I've fetch = lazy.

Comment: 'its still looping' what is looping exactly? How are you determining that in the user. address.user.address is fetched without.. fetching it? Something could be calling getXXX on your model - either you directly, your serialization process, a toString or even the IDE inspecting the code. What JPA provider are you using? I just checked and you are using oneToOne mappings, where JPA providers may require 'more', like byte code enhancement to be able to handle lazy loading for you. (that, and the mapping looks like it should use 'mapped by' and a foreign key somehow, not both use their ID column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Serializers call getters to serialize data which are intercepted by the `Hibernate Proxy` loading the data even if they are lazy. To prevent this, You have to add `@JsonBackReference` to the `address` field in your `User` class, and `@JsonManagedReference` to the `user` field in your `Address` class.

Comment: This worked - Results are returned in a fraction of a previous time it took. Thanks so much for helping!